# Gulp missing the SASS executable

Tags: ruby, windows, node.js, windows-8.1, gulp

I'm working with gulp, I'm trying to install packages and the only way to install gulp on windows is to type npm install -g gulp@3.8.7 because new versions print me in the console some errors about the v8flags package. 
So I'm trying to compile sass through Gulp. I've a gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return sass('css/main.scss')
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Error', err.message);
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css/main.css'));
});
```

But Everytime I type "gulp sass" the console prints:

```
Error Missing the SASS executable. Please install and make it available on your PATH.
```

I have included the directory of my ruby bin in the PATH var (system variables within Enviroment variables).

I'm on Windows 8.1

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

node -v 
v0.10.29

npm -v
1.4.14

sass -v
Sass 3.4.8 (Selective Steve)
```

Comment: Did you ever get around this? I found this, which may help: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/blob/master/readme.md#note-pre-10-versions-are-no-longer-supportedplease-try-100-alpha  I hit the same error on Linux and that helped me through it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I did

```
sudo gem install sass
```

and that added the sass executable to my path.

Comment: I'm on Windows Machine